# Making TFS include the Published WCF Services in release build

Tags: wcf, tfs, build, tfsbuild

We have a release build where we want all the WebApps and WCF Services included as separate zipfiles in the build.

The release build includes all our solutions in "Items to build" on the Process page of the build.

We use the following "MSBuild Arguments" on the Process page:

```
"/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:DeployOnBuild=True"
```

This works great for the Web Application projects, these are zipped and included, so we can unzip them from a Powershell script and deploy them on a server.

However the "WCF Services Library"-projects and "WCF Service Application"-projects are not included.

I've also tried setting the

```
<DeployOnBuild>True</DeployOnBuild> 
<CreatePackageOnPublish>True</CreatePackageOnPublish>
```

in the csproj file, but it did not get included (as explained in http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/11/team-build-web-deployment-web-deploy-vs.html)

Does anybody know how to make MSBuild also include the "WCF Services Library"-projects?

We use TFS 2011, but it should be compliant with TFS 2010

Comment: A WCF service library is just a class library of WCF service code. It's not something to be separately deployed. The WCF service application should be getting depoyed, though. Does it deploy in Debug mode?

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing this would be to have an Asp.net website which acts as host to the WCF service library in the same solution which just references the WCF service library and has its .svc file.

So now when you trigger a TFS build you will be able to have the Asp.net website  in the "_PublishedWebsites" folder which essentially means you have managed to publish the WCF Service using TFS.